# Performing a query via REST-API - Solve encoding problems

Tags: rest-api, php

I am using Guzzle as my PHP HTTP client to perform api-calls.
This worked great so far, for retrieving my access-token for example.

However, now that I am trying to perform a query search I get a strange Error:

```
SELECT+Name+FROM+Account\n ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:6\n unexpected token: '+'
```

This is my code for performing my request:

```
try {
            $response = $client->get( 'services/data/v55.0/query/', [
                RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                ],
                'query' => [
                    'q' => 'SELECT+Name+FROM+Account',
                ],
                /*'debug' => true*/
            ] );

            $data = json_decode( $response->getBody(), true );

            return $data;

        }
        catch ( \Exception $exception ) {
            echo $exception;
            /*refreshAccessToken();*/
            /*continue;*/
        }
```

As pointed out by @sfdcfox, guzzle encodes my query string. Unfortunately, when I pass my query directly to my url, or append it to the request using the JSON requestOption it does not get recognized by Salesforce. How can I perform my query with guzzle without encoding my query, and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guzzle uses `http_build_query`, which in turn automatically encodes characters for you using `PHP_QUERY_RFC1738` by default. In other words, your literal `+` are being encoded, and on the far end, when decoded, becomes the literal query `SELECT+Name+FROM+Account`, which isn't valid SOQL. Just write the query "normally", and it should work.

```
try {
    $response = $client->get( 'services/data/v55.0/query/', [
        RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'query' => [
            'q' => 'SELECT Name FROM Account',
        ],
        /*'debug' => true*/
    ] );

    $data = json_decode( $response->getBody(), true );

    return $data;

}
catch ( \Exception $exception ) {
    echo $exception;
    /*refreshAccessToken();*/
    /*continue;*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!! What exactly do you mean by writing the query "normally"?

Comment: @FewtureWebdesign Just plain, unencoded text. The framework takes care of encoding special chars for you.

Comment: Does that mean, that I can not use Guzzle for this? I have no clue where to put the query string. If I put it outside the 'query' request option, it does not get recognized by Salesforce.

Comment: @FewtureWebdesign `'q' => 'SELECT+Name+FROM+Account',` should be `'q' => 'SELECT Name FROM Account',` My apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: You helped me a lot, thank you for that!! It worked perfectly!